# formatted my external ext4 HDD to exfat by mistake - any way to get the data back?

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, data-loss

I know this type of question is frequent, but mostly they seem to relate to *only* deleting a partition, and not a case where a new partition has been made afterwards. The different guides says Testdisk is the answer. I'm on a Lubuntu 17.10 machine.

So, I have a couple of HDDs in my computer, for data storage. I wanted to format (the only) partition on /dev/sdf to exfat. So I did this:

```
sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdf1
```

However, I made a mistake and wrote:

```
sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1
```

Which formatted my entire storage location with pictures from my childhood etc... pretty stupid. (*Yes, I should have a backup, but I didn't*). It also has only one partition on the HDD.

Normally, I would just try some different things, but in this particular case, I'm afraid that by mangling anymore with the newly created partition on `/dev/sdb1` I could make it impossible to recover the data.

Here is a screenshot from `photorec` and the HDD:

[image: photorec screenshot]

However, when I press enter at either one of these three options, the default action in the next menu, for the type of filesystem to recover, isn't "ext2/ext3/ext4" but the "other" category

[image: photorec filesystem type]

I know the deleted partition was ext4, so this makes me worried.

Comment: the program `photorec` from `testdisk` package can recover datas

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I have updated my question accordingly (since it didn't solve it)

Comment: type `photorec` in a terminal its a file recovery tool

Comment: I know, check my question again - as I wrote, I updated it to reflect how far photorec got me.